# CoffeeScript editor for MacOS

Tags: macos, coffeescript

Does anybody know a good text editor for Mac that supports syntax highlighting in CoffeeScript? Is it possible to do this in TextWrangler or BBEdit?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Espresso 2](https://espressoapp.com/) has [CoffeeScript.sugar](https://github.com/artisonian/CoffeeScript.sugar)

Answer (score 41):

On http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/ there is a list of what is available.

For Emacs there is [CoffeeScript Major Mode](http://github.com/defunkt/coffee-mode) (Emacs for mac: http://aquamacs.org/)

For Vim there is [Vim CoffeeScript](http://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script) (Vim for mac: http://code.google.com/p/macvim/)

For [Textmate](http://macromates.com/) there is [CoffeeScript TextMate Bundle](http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle) (how noted by Trevor, this is maintained by CoffeeScript creator Jeremy Ashkenas. And how noted by [Chocohound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/526098/chocohound), it works on [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) too)

For Gedit there is [gedit-coffeescript](http://github.com/wavded/gedit-coffeescript)

For IntelliJ IDEA and RubyMine there is [coffeescript-idea](http://yeungda.github.com/coffeescript-idea/)

<strike>I can find nothing for TextWrangler or BBEdit</strike>.

**Edit:**

The list moved to the [wiki](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/wiki/Text-editor-plugins) and now there is an attempt to make a BBEdit plugin too ;)

As [mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21) said, you can find [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler/) instructions [here](http://joyofmodeling.org/index.php/OSX/coffeescript-syntax-coloring-in-text-wrangler.html).

Comment: You can install Gedit on a mac too ;) http://projects.gnome.org/gedit/screenshots.html

Comment: It should be noted that the bundle for TextMate is maintained by CoffeeScript creator Jeremy Ashkenas, so it's the closest thing to an "official" bundle.

Comment: Sublime Text 2 works well, and can use the tmLanguage and tmPreferences files from Jeremy Ashkenas.  See http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2022&start=10

Comment: I use the vim plugin.  It's far more awesome than I expected: it auto-compiles the coffeescript into javascript every time I save from vim.  And if there are any errors, it opens them up in a window.  Amazing!

Comment: You can add it to TextWrangler: http://joyofmodeling.org/index.php/OSX/coffeescript-syntax-coloring-in-text-wrangler.html

Answer (score 9):

To highlight coffeescript in Eclipse:

1. Download
   http://www.gstaff.org/colorEditor/cbg.editor_1.2.6.jar
2. Download https://raw.github.com/dhotson/coffeescript-jedit/master/coffeescript.xml
3. Open cbg.editor_1.2.6.jar with a zip editor.
4. Put coffeescript.xml into the cbg.editor_1.2.6.jar\modes directory
5. Edit cbg.editor_1.2.6.jar\modes\catalog (it's an XML file)
6. Add a line for Coffeescript:

`<MODE NAME="coffee"        FILE="coffeescript.xml"
                FILE_NAME_GLOB="*.coffee" />`

Save the .jar and put it into Eclipse's plugin directory. Restart Eclipse and .coffee files should now be highlighted.

WARNING: For some reason, this plugin's default colours are **TERRIFYINGLY UNUSABLE**. I recommend editing the colours to the attached first, before viewing any files. Honestly, just save yourself the heartache.

[image: Colour preferences in Eclipse]

Comment: I wrote a script that automates downloading and modifying the jar as you describe. It includes some additional steps that I found helpful. Feel free to edit it to suit your own needs:

https://github.com/bolinfest/coffee-script/blob/master/patch-color-editor.sh

Comment: `bash < <(curl https://raw.github.com/bolinfest/coffee-script/master/patch-color-editor.sh)`

Comment: @bolinfest: I'm on Mac and I haven't installed `wget` command, infact launching your script I get `patch-color-editor.sh: line 18: wget: command not found`. To get it works you have to save the script replacing `wget` command with `curl -O`.

Answer (score 7):

TextMate have good bundle:

[TextMate bundle](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script-tmbundle)

RubyMine / IDEA have also good plugin (but this is IDE and is crossplatform):

[Idea plugin](http://yeungda.github.com/coffeescript-idea/)

Comment: Most always there's a TextMate bundle for anything you'd want to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks, Andrzej. I guess I will finally have to learn to like TextMate :)

Answer (score 1):

Aptana has it now in version 3.0.4, but due to a bug with control over tabs/spaces, you'll need to install the 3.0.5 beta.

This is the beta Eclipse update site: http://preview.appcelerator.com/aptana/studio3/plugin/update/beta/

I'm pretty happy with Aptana. In my opinion, the editors for css, scss, coffeescript, html, etc. are all better than the built-in eclipse editors for these languages.

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe Brackets](https://web.archive.org/web/20140320060205/http://download.brackets.io/) has native CoffeeScript support and the 'Interactive Linter' extension (downloadable from within the app) will even lint it to some extent, tell you that your lines are too long and so on.

However, there is no comment/uncomment keyboard shortcut, which gets old fast and there are other bugs, as you'd expect with software in such hard-development.

Worth checking out, none-the-less.

Answer (score 0):

Did you give [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) a try?

Comment: where have you found eclipse support for coffeescript?

Comment: @GUARD - i think you should be able to configure eclipse to format CoffeeScript as desired

Comment: I was able to get Coffeescript syntax coloring in Eclipse using the Color Editor plugin and the jEdit coffeescript.xml mode available. Contact me for details if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plist file for syntax highlighting, etc, for CoffeeScript in BBEdit:

https://gist.github.com/3219871